Microtype tracking inserts spaces in small caps in biblatex biber bibliography
I'm sorry if this is just me not understanding or doing something properly, but I seem to have uncovered a strange interaction between microtype's tracking feature and biblatex/babel. Please consider the MWE below:
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[%
  babel=true,%
  tracking=true
]{microtype}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{biblio.bib}
@book{saussureCourseGeneralLinguistics1959,
  title = {Course in General Linguistics},
  author = {family=Saussure, given=Ferdinand, prefix=de, useprefix=false},
  date = {1959},
  publisher = {Philosophical Library},
  location = {New York},
  isbn = {978-0-231-15726-1},
  langid = {english},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{saussureCourseGeneralLinguistics1959}

An ordinary small-caps word is benefiting from tracking and copied text is OK:
\begin{center}
  \textsc{Saussure}
\end{center}

\vspace{1em}

The bibliography with tracking and small caps on the other hand gives:

\printbibliography[heading=none]{}

Which when copied is understood as:

\begin{center}
\texttt{S au s s u r e}
\end{center}

\vspace{1em}

And switching off tracking fixes it:

\microtypesetup{tracking=false}
\printbibliography[heading=none]{}

Copied this is understood as:

\begin{center}
\texttt{Saussure}
\end{center}

\end{document}


This showed up when my PhD advisor complained that she couldn't find Saussure in my bibliography... well, he's there sure enough, but using "Find" in the PDF to search for "Saussure" doesn't work does it... you'd need to search for "S au s s u r e" 
I guess the easy way is just to turn off tracking in the bibliography like I did here in the MWE, but is this normal behaviour? I wondered if the PDF viewer could be at fault but I tried several and (Okular and Firefox pdf.js) and both see the text in the same way.
Thanks in advance for any help.
Regards,

Welcome! I can't reproduce this. Specifically, I cannot reproduce the distinction between the document body case and the bibliography case. if I compile your code, no instance where tracking is used copies correctly and none are found using the search function of my pdf viewer. I tested with both pdfTeX and luaTeX. as far as I can tell, tracking breaks the underlying representation of the text and, so, both copy-paste and search. I used okular to test.

in practical terms, I would strongly advise you against using this feature anywhere in your dissertation. even if you find some kind of solution, do you really want to risk it not working for your examination committee?

Hi @cfr, and thanks for looking into this. I just copy-pasted this MWE into overleaf to check and indeed, it breaks both the normal \textsc part and the bibliography. I agree it's a bit scary that this could happen and makes me want to err on the side of caution too... Bit mysterious why on my machine the textsc part doesn't get any extra spaces though, only in the bibliography

you'd probably have to examine the pdfs for differences. different versions? it shouldn't be differences in OS, but I guess it could be if there's a bug. there have been changes in this area because tex doesn't traditionally output spaces at all, but accessible pdf will require them. I don't know if that could be connected or if it's completely unrelated. which engine do you use locally and which OS and TeX distribution?

I'm on Arch Linux, using Texlive 2024.2. I tested with pdfLaTeX and get the same result as you and Overleaf, and with LuaLaTeX it inserts the spaces only in the bibliography. I've created an issue on microtype github: https://github.com/schlcht/microtype/issues/41

As I say, I can't reproduce the different luatex behaviour. I checked with texlive 2023 and 2024, I'm also using arch, though our environments may still be quite different. I tested the behaviour in okular on x11. but maybe somebody else will be able to reproduce ....

pdf viewers use heuristics to determine whether a space should be regarded as a real space or just as kerning. In your case, the amount of letterspacing is obviously so much that your viewer mistakenly sees them as real spaces. You could use less letterspacing (the default is a bit much anyway): letterspace=50 in microtype's options, or use the accsupp package.

PS. see here, which is the same issue really, only using soul instead of microtype for letterspacing.

Just as a data point the wonderful SumatraPDF (on Windows) pastes "Saussure" everywhere with pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. So does Microsoft Edge's PDF renderer. (In contrast Firefox's pdf.js shows the problematic behaviour as already mentioned several times.)

Suppose the following test:
\fontfam[lm]

Test is test.                          % normal text 

{\setletterspace{10}\rm Test is test.} % tracked text

\bye

When we create a PDF from this (by OpTeX) and extract the core information from the PDF format (I rewrite it using more understandable PostScript instructions), then we can get:
...
(T) show -83 0 rmoveto (est) show 333 0 rmoveto (is) show 333 0 rmoveto (test.) show
...
(T) show 100 0 rmoveto (e) show 100 0 rmoveto (s) show 100 0 rmoveto
(t) show 433 0 rmoveto (i) show 100 0 rmoveto
(s) show 433 0 rmoveto (t) show 100 rmoveto (e) show
100 0 rmoveto  (s) show 100 0 rmoveto (.) show
...

PDF viewer is working with this sort of information. It must restore the fact that (T) show -83 0 rmoveto (est) show is the word Test. The space between T and e is here due to kerning between these two letters. The kerning can be positive too. So, PDF viewer must decide that the space is "sufficiently small" and that the original is probably a single word. But what does mean "sufficiently small"? How feel this rmoveto a human reader? This is complicated question when you are implementing a PDF interpreter which must to reconstruct the origial words. We cannot be surprised that such an implementation is not 100% reliable.
From your example: S au s s u r e: the PDF interpreter decided that the space between a and u is "small" and it created the word "au". Other spaces are big and seems like word spaces from PDF interpreter point of view. Various PDF interpreters can implement this feature differently.

Interesting! I thought the whole point of PDFs was that they should be Portable... It comes as something of a surprise to me that there is any room at all in the PDF spec for such "heuristics". It seems like it wouldn't be so hard for the specification to require that such things be hardcoded so as to leave no room for interpretation. That was always what I felt that "Portable" was supposed to mean...

Here is a very similar discussion of people using tracking in InDesign (so an expensive piece of Adobe software, presumably up to spec on PDF creation) and obtaining whitespace in the PDF: https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/indesign-kerning-and-tracking-converted-to-white-space-when-exporting-to-pdf/m-p/12948283 . OP ends up writing "using any PDF reader app other than Acrobat gives same results. Conclusion: there is no way to avoid the creation of white space characters when using certain tracking values in ANY application. "
